# How to match a text node then follow parent nodes using XPath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse some HTML with XPath. Following the simplified XML example below, I want to match the string 'Text 1', then grab the contents of the relevant `content` node.

```
<doc>
    <block>
        <title>Text 1</title>
        <content>Stuff I want</content>
    </block>

    <block>
        <title>Text 2</title>
        <content>Stuff I don't want</content>
    </block>
</doc>
```

My Python code throws a wobbly:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> tree = etree.XML("<doc><block><title>Text 1</title><content>Stuff 
I want</content></block><block><title>Text 2</title><content>Stuff I d
on't want</content></block></doc>")
>>>
>>> # get all titles
... tree.xpath('//title/text()')
['Text 1', 'Text 2']
>>>
>>> # match 'Text 1'
... tree.xpath('//title/text()="Text 1"')
True
>>>
>>> # Follow parent from selected nodes
... tree.xpath('//title/text()/../..//text()')
['Text 1', 'Stuff I want', 'Text 2', "Stuff I don't want"]
>>>
>>> # Follow parent from selected node
... tree.xpath('//title/text()="Text 1"/../..//text()')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1330, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/
lxml/lxml.etree.c:14542)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 287, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__ca
ll__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:90093)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 209, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handl
e_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:89446)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 194, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise
_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:89281)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid type
```

Is this possible in XPath? Do I need to express what I want to do in a different way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you want that?

```
//title[text()='Text 1']/../content/text()
```

Comment: Duh, simple really! Kinda makes sense that I'm selecting the text() attribute now.

Comment: you can also use //block[title='Text 1']/content to get the relevant content node

Comment: @Dror: Now that's useful to know.

Answer (score 16):

**Use**:

```
string(/*/*/title[. = 'Text 1']/following-sibling::content)
```

**This represents at least two improvements** as compared to the currently accepted solution of Johannes Weiß:

1. **The very expensive abbreviation "//"** (usually causing the whole XML document to be scanned) **is avoided** as it should be whenever the structure of the XML document is known in advance.
2. **There is no return back to the parent** (the location step "/.." is avoided)

Comment: Fair improvement, my actual document is HTML and the 'title' part is nested about five levels deep so I have to go back about five parents to get to the 'content' area. I'll bear the first point in mind, though it'll make little difference for a dirty hack.

Comment: What does `/*/*/` do? I'm trying it on a fairly big document and it seems as slow as `//`.

Comment: @dentarg: `/*/*` selects all elements that are children of the top element of the document. It is way faster than `//someName` which traverses the complete document and selects every element named `"someName"`. In this answer we can use an even more efficient expression: `string(/*/*/title[. = 'Text 1'][1]/following-sibling::content)` The expression in the answer shouldn't be less efficient, given a well-optimizing XPath processor -- because whenever the `string()` function is provided an argument that is a node-set, it only produces the string value of the first node of this node-set.