# nokogiri xpath expressions not parsing

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri 1.3.3 with Ruby 1.8.7  I am trying to match the content of a tag as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598722/how-to-match-a-text-node-then-follow-parent-nodes-using-xpath):

```
nodeset.xpath("entry/index[. = '#{index.to_s}']/../categories")
```

Nokogiri raises an exception complaining about the '`.`' after the bracket.  When I replace the '`.`' with `text()` it then complains about the second period.  Is this me or Nokogiri?  How do I fix it

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your document structure correctly, you should be able to do:

```
nodeset.xpath("entry[index='#{index.to_s}']/categories")
```

which seems more readable to me.

Comment: Ok, But my example is a valid xpath why will it not parse?  This is not the only time this has come up.

Comment: Odd - your exact xpath works for me (Nokogiri 1.3.3, Ruby 1.8.6 and/or 1.9.1).  What version of libxml2 are you using?